# IE incorrect usage of :active selector

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

I am using the `:active` selector to attempt to style links whilst the mouse button is pressed against them.

This works fine in cool browsers, however IE 8/7 (The only versions I can test with) manage to show the style however the element keeps it's `:active` styling after the button is depressed and the `:active` style also fires when the element has keyboard `:focus` (I believe this is the same bug as the element gets keyboard `:focus` after it is clicked).

Does anyone know a non-javascript work around?

A live example can be seen at: http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/communication/ (Try the buttons below the breadcrumb navigation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get `:active` working as you want it in IE7. If you can get it to work with javascript then that would be your best bet. IE8 and 9 should work perfectly in your example page above, it certainly seems to from my end. Other implementations of `:active` may not work as expected, such as in nested elements, but in your case it seems to work fine.

See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html for information on compatibility.

Comment: My cut off point for support is IE7 with javascript so that's ok, but I need to support IE8 without javascript and it is definitely not working correctly for me. After you click the button it keeps `:focus` and the `:active` state isn't removed like it should be.

Comment: It definitely isn't working like that for me. IE8 is working as expected.

Comment: Perhaps you are using a higher version of IE8 what is your version number? Mine is 8.0.6001.18702

Comment: 8.0.7600.16385 but it shouldn't matter. It should work in all versions.

Comment: they have been known for changing implementation in minor revision numbers

Comment: I don't believe there should be any difference in functionality between minor versions. But I could be wrong.